# Error when convert JSON into an Object javax.json.bind.JsonbException: Can't create instance of a class: class [Lclass;, No default constructor found

Tags: java, jax-rs

First of all what iam using.

Server: Wildfly 20.0.1

IntelliJ

Open JDK 14

Github Repo: https://github.com/FreshDoktor/MinecraftApi-Stackoverflow

The full log: https://pastebin.com/XGEYuuWG

Standalone: https://pastebin.com/9FYwFNvB

I already double checked if my class overwriting the default constructor its not the case.
Also the L in front of the class in the message is not an typo. Thats what is written in my console.

Iam writing an Service with JEE and try to convert an response from JSON to an Object. To get the response i used the client from javax.ws.rs.

Unfortunately I have no idea what the problem could be and hope to get my mistake explainded her.

Enclosed you will find the class and method which I think are important for the error. Also i uploaded my project to git so you can look into every file you need.

Thanks in advance.

```
@PostConstruct
    public void contextInitialized() {
        System.out.println("StartupListener.contextInitialized - Start");
        Client client = ClientBuilder.newClient();
        List<FullMinecraftVersionEntity> objects = Arrays.asList(client.target("https://launchermeta.mojang.com/mc/game/version_manifest.json") //
                        .request(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON) //
                        .get(FullMinecraftVersionEntity[].class));
        System.out.println(objects);
        System.out.println("StartupListener.contextInitialized - End");
    }
```

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "FULL_VERSION")
public class FullMinecraftVersionEntity {
    @Id
    @Column(name = "ID")
    private String id;

    @Column(name = "TYPE")
    private String type;

    @Column(name = "URL")
    private String url;

    @Column(name = "TIME")
    private String time;

    //Getter Setter

    @Override
    public String toString() {
       
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object o) {
        
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        return Objects.hash(getId(), getType(), getUrl(), getTime(), getReleaseTime());
    }

}
```

Comment: The [L means array. You are trying to create an array, that's what you are passing to `get(FullMinecraftVersionEntity[].class)`. I don't work much with JSONB, but you can try `new GenericType<List<FullMinecraftVersionEntity>>(){}` instead of the array class. This will return a list so you don't need to wrap itin Arrays.asList().

Comment: Thanks that already helped my a lot, I thought it maby connected with that L added in the console. I will try it when Iam back from work.

Answer (score 2):

I've got it, the object i want to deserialize and the json response did not match up.